# Socket.IO - Value of type 'WebSocket' has no member 'onHttpResponseHeaders'

Tags: ios, socket.io, cocoapods

This is my pod file :

```
target 'Test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test
  pod 'Alamofire', '4.5.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
  pod 'Starscream', '<= 3.0.5'

end
```

Getting this error in **SocketEngine.swift** class of **Socket.IO** :

> Value of type 'WebSocket' has no member 'onHttpResponseHeaders'

in the following code :

```
ws?.onHttpResponseHeaders = {[weak self] headers in
    guard let this = self else { return }

    this.client?.engineDidWebsocketUpgrade(headers: headers)
}
```

I am using Xcode 9.4 with Swift 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onHttpResponseHeaders` was [introduced](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/commit/46d8cacb2e9b86e1286f0683c89a014b0dfeb848) in `Starscream 3.1.0`. Change the version of the pod in this line:

```
pod 'Starscream', '~> 3.1'
```

Or remove this line at all and CocoaPods will handle dependency automatically.